# If 1 or 2 cells are blank then

Tags: excel

I'm trying to write a simple formula to check whether either 1 or both cells are blank and, if so, leave the resulting cell blank. I want the resulting cell to only display a calculation if both cells are filled in.

I've got this do far though it doesn't work as I wanted: `=IF(OR(C4<>"",B4<>""),A4-C4,"")`

b4 has a date and c4 has a numeric value (4). the formulate is in d4. I want to check if b4 or c4 are blank and, if so, leave d4 blank too, else take c4 from a4 (14 as of now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try this formula

```
=IF(AND(C4<>"",B4<>""),A4-C4,"")
```

Answer (score 6):

It should work:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(C4);"";IF(ISBLANK(D4);"";A4-C4))
```

It checks if C4 is a blank cell, if not then checks if D4 is blank, if not then does the math.

Comment: Certain versions of Excel use comma separators instead of semicolons.  `=IF(ISBLANK(C4),"",IF(ISBLANK(D4),"",A4-C4))`

Answer (score 4):

I recommend using ISBLANK to check for blank cells.

Formula for your D4:

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(B4), ISBLANK(C4)),,A4-C4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, I used `=IF(A2&B2="",TRUE VALUE, FALSE VALUE)` which worked great

Comment: Can you please format the code and add some explanation?