# If two cells have information, then add text to a third cell

Tags: excel

I want to check two cells and if both are filled in I would like to have the term 'Switch' in my third cell.

I found some information about doing this with blank celss (e.g. **[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27439738/if-1-or-2-cells-are-blank-then#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27439738/if-1-or-2-cells-are-blank-then#_=_)**). However, I would like to do the same with filled cells. I tried several things, only it did not work so far...

Help is very appreciated.

Comment: `IF(AND(A1<>"",B1<>""),"Swtich","")`???

Comment: In C1: `IF(A1<>"",IF(B1<>"", "Switch",""),"")`

Answer (score 0):

Assume that the two cells are A1 and A2, and the third is B1; then, you would enter in B1:

```
=IF(AND(A1<>"",A2<>""),"Switch","")
```

where `Switch` is the text you will see in B1 when the other cells have something (of course, you can change this to whatever you need).

**UPDATE**

As wisely pointed out by @Andreas (see below) it turns out that `;` **IS** the correct delimiter in certain locales. As such, if you get an error when using `,`, switch back to `;`.

Comment: I get the point, only it now also places 'Switch' at rows where only one cell is filled in. What do I need to change to only fill in 'Switch' when both cells are filled in? Now I used the code `=IF(AND(F4<>G4<>"");"Switch";"")`.

Comment: @Keizer You are not using the same code as any of us has given you. You see that, right?

Comment: Check your code: you have a couple of errors in `=IF(AND(F4<>G4<>"");"Switch";"")`. (1) `F4<>G4<>""` should be `F4<>"",G4<>""` (check the logic and you will understand why); (2) the syntax (at least this is what I know) is: `IF(<test condition>,<result if true>,<result if false>)` using `,` and not `;`.

Comment: @FDavidov Don't say that he shouldn't use `;` it depends on his regional settings. Most European versions of Excel have `;`

Comment: @Andreas, please refer to what I wrote in parenthesis _(at least this is what I know)_. I'm not using any European locale. By the way, and just for my curiosity, if you use `,` you get an error?

Comment: Yes. You get an error. In the case we have here the formula will return an error as it expects a delimiter. Or there is not enough arguments

Comment: I see... I wonder why MS did that (condition syntax of formulae/functions to local settings). Anyway, thanks for the info.

Comment: Thanks @FDavidov and @ Andreas, now I see the mistake. Thanks :) And yes, when I use `,` I get an error.

Comment: It's because (again) most European countries have `,` as decimal separator and `.` as thousands separator. That means none of them work for formula delimiter :-)

Comment: No problem! :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you check A1, and B1 cells, C1 you expect to show "Switch", then in C3 place:

```
=IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(A1)), NOT(ISBLANK(B1))),"Switch","")
```

As mentioned above, you may be using ";" instead of "," in your formula based on regional settings.